# Azure blob storage - Is virtual directory has child?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to show all the azure blob's virtual directory in file explorer view. When create folder from this file explorer, I have uploaded on dummy file within that folder.
Ex: If I need to create xyz folder, I will upload a file with "https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/container/xyz/dummyfile.txt" this name. When list the folder & file details, excluded a dummmyfile.txt.

The above scenario is working fine. I'm facing small issue here. Below snap, + icon will be shown to every folder, which has child folder/file. I need one more attribute called HasChild to do this feature. Is there any way to get this information?

[image]

Note:
For temporary fix, I did this with below code:

```
var containerDetail = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var hasChild = containerDetail.ListBlobs(virtualDirectoryPath).Count > 1;
```

Comment: Did you try this approach? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4da1ed17-c2fa-45c4-b8a7-38fc904c2b6b/check-if-azure-folder-exists?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

Comment: Me too tried that approach. Here I have used count > 1, because, I had uploaded one dummy file while creating folder. We can't create a empty directory in Azure blob.

Answer (score 0):

Azure blob storage is binary file storage only. There's no underlying operating system that implements folders or file pointers, so you can only model it through the use of the binary filename. The convention to pretend there is a folder structure is to use slashes, but you could just as easily use underscores, hash marks or double at signs if you really wanted to. In order to model that though you have to upload an empty file that has the folder structure built into the name - as you're seeing with the count > 1.

There's a good article on CodeProject that talks about [modelling directory structures using Azure Blob Storage](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/597939/modelingplusaplusdirectoryplusstructureplusonplusa).